# How to make necessary changes to Geodataframe to export as geopackage or shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, geodataframe, osmnx

I am trying to export a geodatabase I created via the [OMSNX package](https://geoffboeing.com/publications/osmnx-complex-street-networks/). ()

When I attempt to convert the file from a geodatabase to shapefile I get an error "ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'list'>". This is because the geodatabase has some formats that are not compatible with shapefiles as mentioned here under the [spatial data section](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/io.html).

How do I convert the geodataframe to allow for an export as a shapefile? My code and attached error are below.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox
import fiona as fi
print(fi.supported_drivers)
%matplotlib inline
ox.__version__

place = "Dickinson, Texas"
tags = {"building": True}
gdf = ox.geometries_from_place(place, tags)
gdf.shape



fig, ax = ox.plot_footprints(gdf, figsize=(8, 8))
gdf.shape
gdf.to_file('testgalvy.gpkg',driver='GPKG')
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I get `"ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'list'>".` it is when I am trying to convert a geodataframe which has a string/object field with lists in it to shapefile. Do you have lists in a column?

You can convert them to strings by doing:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[['a','list','in','the','column'],'b','c']}) #Create some test data


   a                           b
0  1  [a, list, in, the, column]
1  2                           b
2  3                           c

df['b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x)) #Join the list into a string

   a                     b
0  1  a list in the column
1  2                     b
2  3                     c
```

If you have alot of data you can check all columns like this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if any(isinstance(val, list) for val in df[col]):
        print('Column: {0}, has a list in it'.format(col))
Column: b, has a list in it
```