# Exporting list-type field using GeoPandas

Tags: python, export, geopandas, geopackage, list

I have a GeoDataFrame whose a column is list-type.

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'list': [[0,1]]}, geometry=[Point(0, 0)])
print(gdf)

# OUT:
#      list                 geometry
# 0  [0, 1]  POINT (0.00000 0.00000)
```

When I try to save it as GeoPackage/SQLite/GeoJSON using the following lines, it arises  `ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'list'>`.

```
gdf.to_file("c:/path/to/output.gpkg", driver='GPKG')
gdf.to_file("c:/path/to/output.geojson", driver='GeoJSON')
gdf.to_file("c:/path/to/output.sqlite", driver='SQLite')
```

But interestingly, I can add a list-type fields to SQLite and GeoJSON files in QGIS.

How can I save a GeoDataFrame containing list-type column while keeping the list (without converting it to string)?

Comment: There is a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70943128/5569709) and a [gis se post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411323/29431), but both suggests converting to string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, I will encounter the same `ValueError` error after trying your code:

```
  ...
  File "fiona\\ogrext.pyx", line 1409, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.writerecs
  File "fiona\\ogrext.pyx", line 514, in fiona.ogrext.OGRFeatureBuilder.build
ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'list'>
```

It is happening because Fiona does not support fields with `dict` or `list` when exporting a `GeoDataFrame` in a geodata format. You can find more information in this thread: [invalid field type <class 'list'> while writing a file](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/738).

Luckily, there are workarounds, that can protect your `list` field.

### Approach 1 : the [`to_parquet()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_parquet.html#geopandas-geodataframe-to-parquet) method

It will export `GeoDataFrame` to a [GeoParquet](https://geoparquet.org/) file format. Since GeoPandas 0.8 version.

```py
# imports
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

# creating a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'list': [[0,1]]}, geometry=[Point(29.01054793, 41.05223318)])
gdf = gdf.set_crs(4326, allow_override=True)

# exporting GeoDataFrame to a GeoParquet
gdf.to_parquet("c:/path/to/output.parquet")
```

After one can properly import this *'output.parquet'* into e.g. QGIS, see the image below:

[image: result_1]

If you check the types of the fields in QGIS, for the *'output.parquet'* file:

```py
# imports
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsVariantUtils

# accessing the active layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# getting field's name and type in readable format
for field in layer.fields():
    print(field.name(), ':' , QgsVariantUtils.typeToDisplayString(field.type()))
```

you will see:

```
list : List
```

One will be convinced, that the field `"list"` possesses the [`QVariant.List`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvariant.html#QVariant-21) type.

### Approach 2 : the [`to_json()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_json.html) method

One can easily convert `GeoDataFrame` to a JSON, that can be later exported as a [GeoJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON).

```py
# imports
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

# creating a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'list': [[0,1]]}, geometry=[Point(29.01054793, 41.05223318)])
gdf = gdf.set_crs(4326, allow_override=True)

# converting GeoDataFrame to a JSON
data = gdf.to_json()

# writing JSON data structure to a GeoJSON file
with open("c:/path/to/output.geojson", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

If one does not need the automatically created `"id"` field, use the conversion like: `data = gdf.to_json(drop_id=True)`

Hereafter one can properly import this *'output.geojson'* into e.g. QGIS, see the image below:

[image: result_2]

If you check the types of the fields in QGIS, for the *'output.geojson'* file:

```py
# imports
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsVariantUtils

# accessing the active layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# getting fields names and types in readable format
for field in layer.fields():
    print(field.name(), ':' , QgsVariantUtils.typeToDisplayString(field.type()))
```

you will see:

```
id : Text (string)
list : List
```

One will be again convinced, that the field `"list"` possesses the [`QVariant.List`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvariant.html#QVariant-21) type.

---

**References:**

- [AttributeError when creating list field with QVariant in QgsVectorLayer using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463920/attributeerror-when-creating-list-field-with-qvariant-in-qgsvectorlayer-using-py)
- [Writing properties corresponding to a given schema within the GeoDataFrame.to_file() method?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412355/writing-properties-corresponding-to-a-given-schema-within-the-geodataframe-to-fi)
- [write python 2d list containing list to parquet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68447974/write-python-2d-list-containing-list-to-parquet-file)